# Stuck on Jquery script

Tags: jquery, html, css

My Jquery does not work when I press the burger button

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function)() {
      $('.menu').click(function)() {
          $('.menu').toggleClass('menuc');

      })

  })
```

Comment: Job #1 when debugging JS: **check the console**. `function)() {` is a syntax error in both places. Fix that and your code works: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/b6c7afLm/. Closing as a typographic mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what exactly is the problem, because you have not sent the complete code.

so i suggest you to use this

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

$( ".cross" ).hide();
$( ".menu" ).hide();
$( ".hamburger" ).click(function() {
$( ".menu" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
$( ".hamburger" ).hide();
$( ".cross" ).show();
});
});

$( ".cross" ).click(function() {
$( ".menu" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
$( ".cross" ).hide();
$( ".hamburger" ).show();
});
});

});
```

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 background: #ffffff;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

header {
 width: 100%;
 background: #ffffff;
 height: 60px;
 line-height: 60px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.hamburger {
 background: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 line-height: 45px;
 padding: 5px 15px 0px 15px;
 color: #999;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 1.4em;
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: none;
 z-index: 10000000000000;
}

.cross {
 background: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0;
 padding: 7px 15px 0px 15px;
 color: #999;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 3em;
 line-height: 65px;
 font-weight: bold;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: none;
 z-index: 10000000000000;
}

.menu {
 z-index: 1000000;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 0.8em;
 width: 100%;
 background: #f1f1f1;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 12px;
}

.menu ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 list-style-image: none;
}

.menu li {
 display: block;
 padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
 border-bottom: #dddddd 1px solid;
}

.menu li:hover {
 display: block;
 background: #ffffff;
 padding: 15px 0 15px 0;
 border-bottom: #dddddd 1px solid;
}

.menu ul li a {
 text-decoration: none;
 margin: 0px;
 color: #666;
}

.menu ul li a:hover {
 color: #666;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
}

.menu a:hover {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
}

.glyphicon-home {
 color: white;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 12px;
}

span {
 padding-left: 20px;
}

a {
 color: #336699;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Menu</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <header>
      <span>SITE NAME</span>
      <button class="hamburger">&#9776;</button>
      <button class="cross">&#735;</button>
    </header>

    <div class="menu">
      <ul>
        <a href="#"><li>LIST ONE</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>LIST TWO</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>LIST THREE</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>LIST FOUR</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>LIST FIVE</li></a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```